# sed printing titles

Tags: linux, sed

I am trying to make sed script that takes numbered titles and writes them in tree structure without the numbers:

This is the input:

```
1. Text1
1.1 Text2
1.1.1 Text3
1.1.1.1 Text4
1.1.1.1.1 Text5
2. Text6
2.1 Text7
```

And this would be the desired output with `.` representing spaces:

```
Text1
.Text2
..Text3
...Text4
....Text5
Text6
.Text7
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sed -r 's/^[0-9]+(\. )?//;s/\.[0-9]+/./g;s/^(\.*) /\1/' inputfile
```

This one only outputs the modified lines:

```
sed -rn '/^[0-9]+((\. )|((\.[0-9]+)* ))/{s/^[0-9]+(\. )?//;s/\.[0-9]+/./g;s/^(\.*) /\1/;p}' inputfile
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have one other question. How can this be modified to print only the lines that were modified - the titles?

Comment: @Broom You should not ask additional questions in comments but adjust your question and point to that in a comment. That makes it easier for other readers.

Comment: @Broom if your input can contain lines you do not want modified then you should post a new question that includes such lines in the sample input/output. You should also include examples of "Text", not just say `Text1`, `Text2`, etc. so we can test that a given solution doesn't change parts of the "Text" unexpectedly, e.g. try the posted solutions after replacing `Text1` with `My IP is 1.2.3.4` in your example.

Answer (score 1):

Using any awk on any shell on every Unix box:

```
$ awk '{sub(/\.$/,"",$1); gsub(/[^.]/,"",$1); sub(/ /,"")}1' file
Text1
.Text2
..Text3
...Text4
....Text5
Text6
.Text7
```

To only modify and print the lines that start with the kind of numbering in your question would be something like (untested):

```
awk '/^([0-9]\.)+[0-9]* /{sub(/\.$/,"",$1); gsub(/[^.]/,"",$1); sub(/ /,""); print}' file
```

The above will change all chains of contiguous white space in "Text" to single blank chars. It's easily modified to not do that if that's a problem but, again, you really need to provide sample input/output of "Text" to cover such use cases.